# Rvest - I would like to see what javaScript is being run in browser

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm using Rvest to scrape eBay.  When I run my url in the browser, I get back results just fine.

`https://www.ebay.com/sch/%20Black%20Series%20%20-POTF%20-POTF2%20-POTFII%20-Vintage%20%20Chewbacca&LH_Sold=1&LH_ItemCondition=3&_dmd=7&_ipg=200&LH_Complete=1&LH_PrefLoc=1`

When I use rvest, the initial `read_html()` returns an initial page with some input form data (see image), but not the final data I need.

based on [Page item not scrape-able with rvest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59448073/page-item-not-scrape-able-with-rvest) it seems like I should be able to find the java script that is running, but I don't seem to be able to.

If I have the inspector open in the browser, I can see the data filling in visually.  I believe that java script is running from the initial page return based in form data in the initial returned page.

**Question is**:  How can I find the 2nd call/javaScript url that I need to get the final page results of returned sold items?

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like currently? You can find all the script nodes using something like `xml2::xml_find_all(page, "//script")`. There seem to be 34 different scripts nodes on that page so there is a lot of javascript going on.

Comment: I'm using xpath such as 
`readHTML <- url %>%  read_html()
 Title <- readHTML %>%  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="srp-river-results"]/ul/li/div/div[2]/a/h3') %>% html_text()`

Comment: Then use `readHTML %>% html_nodes("//script")`

Comment: Thank you, I think it needed `xpath=` `script <- readHTML %>% html_nodes(xpath="//script")`